# How do I convert a MultiIndex to type string

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

consider the MultiIndex `idx`

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2013, 2016), range(1, 5)])
```

When I do

```
idx.to_series().str.join(' ')
```

I get

```
2013  1   NaN
      2   NaN
      3   NaN
      4   NaN
2014  1   NaN
      2   NaN
      3   NaN
      4   NaN
2015  1   NaN
      2   NaN
      3   NaN
      4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

This happens because the dtypes of the different levels are `int` and not `str`.  `join` expects a `str`.  How do I convert the whole `idx` to `str`?

I've done

```
join = lambda x, delim=' ': delim.join([str(y) for y in x])
idx.to_series().apply(join, delim=' ')

2013  1    2013 1
      2    2013 2
      3    2013 3
      4    2013 4
2014  1    2014 1
      2    2014 2
      3    2014 3
      4    2014 4
2015  1    2015 1
      2    2015 2
      3    2015 3
      4    2015 4
dtype: object
```

I expect there is a simpler way that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the most elegant way, but it should work:

```
idx.get_level_values(0).astype(str).values + ' ' + idx.get_level_values(1).astype(str).values
```

Comment: This was closest to my intent.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
idx.to_series().apply(lambda x: '{0}-{1}'.format(*x))
```

Comment: this is very similar to what I had already done.  But I like it.

Comment: @piRSquared Right, I didn't realise you wanted a list. You can append `.values` to the line above to get the same output as in the accepted answer.

Comment: See my answer below. I want an efficient and graceful way of converting an index to dtype str

Answer (score 1):

A general solution using `starmap` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import starmap

def flat2(midx, sep=''):
    fstr = sep.join(['{}'] * midx.nlevels)
    return pd.Index(starmap(fstr.format, midx))
```

---

#### Demonstration

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

---

```
flat(midx)
Index([u'13', u'14', u'23', u'24'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
flat(midx, '_')
Index([u'1_3', u'1_4', u'2_3', u'2_4'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest are list comprehensions:

```
print (['{} {}'.format(i[1], i[0]) for i in idx])
print ([' '.join((str(i[0]), str(i[1]))) for i in idx])
```

**Timings**:

```
In [21]: %timeit (['{} {}'.format(i[1], i[0]) for i in idx])
The slowest run took 4.68 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.51 µs per loop

In [22]: %timeit ([' '.join((str(i[0]), str(i[1]))) for i in idx])
The slowest run took 6.48 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.62 µs per loop

In [23]: %timeit (idx.get_level_values(0).astype(str).values + ' ' + idx.get_level_values(1).astype(str).values)
The slowest run took 5.91 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 215 µs per loop

In [24]: %timeit idx.to_series().apply(lambda x: '{0}-{1}'.format(*x))
The slowest run took 5.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 369 µs per loop

In [25]: %timeit idx.to_series().str.join(' ')
The slowest run took 5.53 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 394 µs per loop
```